# Animation is stopping script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, 2d

I have a script that makes the swamp track and follows the player. It workes fine. But when I ad an animation to the enemy (a swamp jumping towards the player) it doesn't move.

I've tried removing the position under animation, but then the swamp does not jump. It just scales. This does though fixe the problem with not following the player. so I think the problem is the animation on the position.

```
public class EnemyAI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;

    private Transform playerPos;

void Update()

    {
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, playerPos.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);

    }

}
```

Comment: Are the gameObjects swamp and enemy same? If not, try adding the animator controller to Swamp and not the enemy.

Comment: yes the swamp is the enemy. and there is an animator controller added

Comment: This is the reason it takes over the position and the script becomes useless. As you have mentioned it jumps (Y-axis) and the position over here takes over. I would suggest try adding a parent to this swamp gameObject and add animation for jumping to this parent. So that animation for jumping is on parent and moveTowards is on child.

Comment: Ill add it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animation is the reason that takes over the position and the script becomes useless. As you have mentioned it jumps (Y-axis) and the position in the animator controller takes over. I would suggest try doing two things:
(a) Add a parent to this swamp gameObject and add animation for jumping to this parent
(b) Add MoveTowards() function to Swamp gameObject.

Through this, the parent gameObject will only perform animation of jumping and the child gameObject will perform MoveTowards() function.